# how to load a url with URLLoader in Adobe Air with javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, air

i am writing an Adobe Air application using flex builder.the application loads a URL using HTML control and URLLoader.

the problem that the page has an instant redirection JavaScript that redirects the page to another one. I would like to disable that redirection.

I think this can be achieved either by disabling JavaScript on page load or telling the HTML control that do not follow the direction. i don't know how to do that?

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey, i found a solution to load html source for a remote html document without loading it in htmlloader.so the javascript will not redirect me.

here is the code (from htmlscout sample application of adobe dev).

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
    function(e:Event):void
    {
        trytogetsource.text = loader.data;
    });
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"));
```